# dynamic icons with the virtual tree component for delphi

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I need to know how to store and load two different icons for each node in the virtual tree component , also the two icons are different in size

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're going to owner-draw the whole thing, no control I'm aware of supports heterogeneous icon sizes, Virtual Treeview include. All icons for a given view are taken from a single `TImageList` control, and `TImageList` only supports one image size at a time.

You can make the icons *appear* to have different sizes by making the image size be that of the larger icon, and then painting the smaller icons onto larger icons that happen to be padded with transparent borders.

If you only need to support one icon size at a time, then you can maintain two separate `TImageList` controls. When you want to switch sizes, reassign the tree control's `ImageList` property. You may also need to adjust the `DefaultNodeHeight` property, along with the heights of all the nodes that already exist.

Comment: thanks alot, yes I know I have to draw every thing , if there is a sample for this would be great

Comment: Faking the size by using transparency around a much smaller image in combination with `OnMeasureItem` to adjust item heights works perfectly here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using TPngImageList. I assume this implementation should work with standard TImageList, but using png images is a better choice.

In this example the form class name is "TfPrj", the TvirtualStringTree instance name is "vPrj", and TMyDataRecord is the record structure where you get your data.

1. Your form has a TVirtualStringTree linked to a TPngImageList with
   16x16 standard icons set. but you want to use for some nodes a 64x64
   icon set.
2. Create your TPngImageList with 64x64 icon set, called iLarge.
3. In you code manage a custom drawing like this.

   ```
   var
     p: TMyDataRecord;

   const
     riskImagesSize=64;
     riskImagesPadding=2;

   procedure FindP(Node: PVirtualNode);
   begin
     // This procedure fill in the "p" record with your tree data for the node.
   end;

   procedure TfPrj.vPrjMeasureItem(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; TargetCanvas: TCanvas;
     Node: PVirtualNode; var NodeHeight: Integer);
   begin
     FindP(Node);
     if p<>nil then
       if p.LargeImages then
         NodeHeight := riskImagesSize+riskImagesPadding*2;

   end;

   procedure TfPrj.vPrjBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
     TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
     CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
   begin
     if Column=0 then begin
       FindP(Node);
       if p<>nil then begin
         if p.LargeImages then begin
           Inc(ContentRect.Left,riskImagesSize);
       end;
     end;
   end;


   procedure TfPrj.vPrjDrawText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; TargetCanvas: TCanvas;
     Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; const Text: string;
     const CellRect: TRect; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
   var
     i: integer;
     s: string;
   begin
     FindP(Node);
     if Column=0 then
       if p<>nil then
         if p.LargeImages then begin
           iLarge.Draw(TargetCanvas,CellRect.Left-riskImagesSize-riskImagesPadding*2,CellRect.Top+riskImagesPadding,p.LargeImagesIndex);
         end;
   end;

   procedure TfPrj.vPrjGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
     Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean;
     var ImageIndex: Integer);
   begin
     if Column<>0 then
       Exit;
     FindP(Node);
     if p.LargeImages then
       ImageIndex=-1
     else
       // Assign the image index for standard TPngImageList

   end;
   ```